# como hacer referencia a un schema en otra carpeta

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

por ejemplo los siguientes esquemas estan las siguientes carpetas

```
cr/user
lms/content
```

este es el esquema contenido

```
user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'cr/user'
    }
```

como puedo referenciar usuario desde el schema contenido?

porque si lo uso asi me sale un error "Schema hasn't been registered for model"

Comment: Esto es imposible de saber? Es supremamente dificil?

Comment: ¡Respondido! PD: al contrario, es super sencillo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás definiendo mal la referencia; ésta **no es la ruta del modelo** es el **nombre** que le das al exportarlo mediante `mongoose.model`.

**Ejemplo**

Si has exportado el modelo `user` de la siguiente manera:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Entonces, la referencia debe ser `User`:

```
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Asi era